# Excluding a particular library from an npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, material-ui

I am making a transition from Material UI to Material UI-Next. They play very nicely together, however Material UI is very intrusive and some of the styles built into their packages I have to override with excessive `!important` rules in CSS. I found that the SvgIcon library forces the color to be black, as you can see in their file here

```
var mergedStyles = (0, _simpleAssign2.default)({
    display: 'inline-block',
    color: svgIcon.color, //  <-- This one!
    fill: this.state.hovered ? onColor : offColor,
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
    userSelect: 'none',
    transition: _transitions2.default.easeOut()
  }, style);
```

If I comment it, my styles work because the color is not restricted to using their color property. **I don't want to use their syntax to define a color**. I am using mdi-material-icons which uses SvgIcon.js from MaterialUI, and the syntax for MaterialUI-Next is different plus I am using theming too. The best approach for me is to ignore the SvgIcon library whilst keeping materialui in my node_modules for other dependencies that are still needed.

p.s. I can't simply comment that color line in the code above because if Material UI updates, (which I doubt it because it's not being maintained any longer but just in case), it will revert the comment block. Plus node_modules are ignored and installed in each developer machine.

So...has anyone ever done this? Keep MaterialUI in the node_modules but uninstall a specific library within it? Furthermore, other developers need to be able to run npm install --save or some npm code to update this change in their machines.

Thanks in advance